# showing RSS feeds on public website, how expensive is that?

Tags: rss, rss-reader

Is it expensive (for bandwidth) too run, say, 30+ rss feeds? I want to let users add RSS feeds so other users can see them too, but I have no idea how much that'll cost me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on how often the feeds are actually read, if you provide any caching mechanisms and so on... Its very hard to put a number on it with the information you are providing.

Just to get you started, I'd do an estimation, such as:

```
 Bandwidth usage per hour = Avg. size per feed entry × Items per Feed ×
                              Total number of feeds on site × Calls per hour
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very expensive.  I suggest you don't do that.